# Converting string to datetime in mapping to viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, entity-framework-6

I have an MVC app where I collect DateTime fields (MM/dd/yyyy) as strings to avoid Chrome overriding the datepicker in bootstrap and to avoid mapping in sqlbulk upload of Excel.  I now need to map this string field back to datetime and am struggling with this greatly.

Here's my Model:

```
public class Something
{
    [Key]
    public string SomeNumber { get; set; }
        ....
    public string SomeDate { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherDate { get; set; }
        ....
}
```

and my ViewModel:

```
public class HistoricalDataVM
{
    .....

    [Display(Name = "Some Date")]
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Some Other Date")]
    public DateTime SomeOtherDate { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

and my controller action:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult SomePartial()
{

    var vm = _ctx.Something.Select(p => new HistoricalDataVM()
    {

        ...

        SomeDate = DateTime.ParseExact(p.SomeDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        SomeOtherDate = DateTime.ParseExact(p.SomeOtherDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),

        ....

    }).OrderByDescending(c => c.SomeDate).ToList();

    return PartialView(vm);
}
```

I have tried "Convert" and DateTime.Parse but all lead to "yellow screen of death" with this error message:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

I have googled and searched SO and can't find a solution that works.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show `DateTime.Parse` or/and `Convert` code examples you used?

Comment: FYI: You could feature-test for browsers that supply their own date pickers and prevent bootstrap from applying in those instances. That's a solvable problem.

Comment: You're right, Cory but that would still require the mapping in sqlbulk method and I have significantly shortened what is a tremendously long model so that's not the only consideration.

Comment: So.. you are storing the dates as strings in the database and passing a VM containing DateTimes to the view? Shouldn't this be the other way around to fix the Chrome problem you described?

Comment: When converting back to DateTime these are display values and not inputs so, no, it has no effect.

Comment: If you think you have a problem with Chrome - you don't. The problem is with your code. You should never be using strings to represent `DateTime` values.

Comment: That's one opinion, but I appreciate it all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first materialize the query to your application and then parse it. Entity Framework doesn't know how to execute dot Net methods, it only knows how to translate them to SQL

Answer (score 0):

you can use DateTime.ParseExact() and set your strict format.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it should give you something like that :

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult SomePartial()
{
    var vm = _ctx.Something.Select(p => new HistoricalDataVM()
    {
            SomeDate = DateTime.ParseExact(p.SomeDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            SomeOtherDate = DateTime.ParseExact(p.SomeOtherDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),

            ....

        }).OrderByDescending(c => c.SomeDate).ToList();

        return PartialView(vm);
    }
```